# Apache drill not running on embeeded mode (ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, apache-drill

I have installed Apache drill version 1.16 but i got this error message when i bin/drill-embedded

[image]

this is my java -version
[image]

and this is my update-alternatives -config java

[image]

and this is my etc/environement[image]

Comment: Could you please check your /etc/environement file, usually JAVA_HOME should point to jre directory:
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre"

Comment: I have already provided that

Comment: I meant to update JAVA_HOME in /etc/environement to 
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre"

Answer (score 0):

This has been closed, i have corrected that by just installing again without pointing to my JAVA HOME because it was already pointed, weird.